# Discord.py ban command, errors

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a ban command, but it spits out an error something with 'BadArgument' here is the code (unban code included):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.member, *, Reason = None):
    if Reason == None:
        bannedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Banned')

        await member.add_roles(bannedRole)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='BANNED', description=f'Banned {member.mention}', colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await member.add_roles(bannedRole)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='BANNED', description=f'Banned {member.mention} for {Reason}', colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member: discord.member):
    bannedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Banned')

    await member.remove_roles(bannedRole)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='UNBANNED', description=f'Unbanned {member.mention}', colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

!!RESOLVED!!

I just needed to do this

```
async def ban(ctx, *, discord.Member, reason==None)
```

I didn't put a capital M after discord.